# Loading data returned as XML from ASMX web service into iPhone/iPad crashes app

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, crash, record, has-many

So, in my app I retreive data from XML web service. Its very huge. Up to the order of 30-40000 records. On simulator it works fine. But on the device it is crashing. I use NSXMLParser. didStartElement,didEndElement. So its crashing at some point. I am however doing this in background thread so as not to break my mainthread. Also to stop iOS to stop kicking out my app if it is longer than 10sec. So any ideas how to correct it.I have been at this hours, but no solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3baa839c __CFBasicHashAddValue + 1452
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3b9d2194 CFBasicHashAddValue + 3048
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3b9d5ebc CFSetAddValue + 112
3   CoreData                        0x3709b5b0 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _insertObjectWithGlobalID:globalID:] + 172
4   CoreData                        0x370939bc -[NSManagedObjectContext insertObject:] + 136
5   CoreData                        0x370836d2 -[NSManagedObject initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] + 646
6   CoreData                        0x3706fd74 +[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 176
7   XYZ Orders                      0x00146c68 -[ITMParser parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:] (ITMParser.m:393)
8   Foundation                      0x36898a82 _endElementNs + 298
9   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x3ad8de5a xmlParseEndTag2 + 614
10  libxml2.2.dylib                 0x3ad8f546 xmlParseTryOrFinish + 1658
11  libxml2.2.dylib                 0x3ad8ece8 xmlParseChunk + 208
12  Foundation                      0x3689755e -[NSXMLParser parse] + 482
13  XYZ Orders                      0x0017a4c4 -[ITMLoginVC getAllCustomerValues] (ITMLoginVC.m:822)
14  XYZ Orders                      0x00176a6c __25-[ITMLoginVC viewDidLoad]_block_invoke_0 (ITMLoginVC.m:218)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x39d8011c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x39d8495c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 248
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x39d84abc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
18  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36ae9a0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
19  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36ae98a0 start_wqthread + 4


- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NAllAddresses"])
{
    NSString *temp=@"";
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
         //The below line happens to be the line number 393.
    ITMAllCustomerAddresses *allCustAddress =(ITMAllCustomerAddresses *)[NSEntityDescription
                                                        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ITMAllCustomerAddresses"
                                                                      inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    allCustAddress.allAddID = [self numberValue:[self.mutableDictionary objectForKey:@"AllAddID"]];
    allCustAddress.allCustID = [self numberValue:[self.mutableDictionary objectForKey:@"AllCustID"]];

    temp =[self.mutableDictionary objectForKey:@"AllAddressLine"];
    allCustAddress.allAddressLine = [self noSpaceString:temp];

    temp = [self.mutableDictionary objectForKey:@"AllAddressCity"];
    allCustAddress.allAddressCity = [self noSpaceString:temp];

    temp = [self.mutableDictionary objectForKey:@"AllAddressState"];
    allCustAddress.allAddressState = [self noSpaceString:temp];

    temp = [self.mutableDictionary objectForKey:@"AllAddressZip"];
    allCustAddress.allAddressZip = [self noSpaceString:temp];

    [self.allCustomerAddressesArray addObject:allCustAddress];
    [self.mutableDictionary removeAllObjects];
}
else
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"AllAddID"]||[elementName isEqualToString:@"AllCustID"] ||[elementName isEqualToString:@"AllAddressLine"]||[elementName isEqualToString:@"AllAddressCity"]||[elementName isEqualToString:@"AllAddressState"]||[elementName isEqualToString:@"AllAddressZip"])
    {
        [self.mutableDictionary setObject:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
        currentElementValue = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: where does it crashes, whats crash log? Post your code..

Comment: @P.J. Added code and crash log. Please check that out.

Answer (score 1):

Did you investigate crash logs from the device? Seems like it is crashing because device is running out of memory. Try parsing smaller file. Also, implement this method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
```

to catch possible parsing errors.

**Update:**

judging from your crash log, you are using Core Data on background thread. Keep in mind that NSManagedObjectContext and NSManagedObject are not thread safe. But NSManagedObjectID is. So if you are parsing XML and creating Core Data objects from it, make sure that you create new instance of NSManagedObjectContext like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *ctx = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[ctx setUndoManager:nil];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[ctx setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];
```

and then use ctx to create new objects.

Comment: Havent done that. But can you tell me if its actually possible to parse 30-40000 records on the go.?Do apps do that? This is my second app. So i dont know much regarding iOS. Also it works fine on simulator. No parsing issues/errors. I get all my 30-40000 records perfectly parsed and saved to core data DB.

Comment: For larger files try using TBXML.

Comment: @Jeepston.I have used the context like you suggested, i can create objects and save them to arrays. But i cant save them to core data DB. I am saving like this  NSError *error = nil;
 if (![ctx save:&error])
 {
  NSLog(@"Failed to save order");
 }. But it wont save. There are no records.

Comment: What does error after saving return? Also, create xml with only one record and run your parsing code on main thread. See if it helps.

Comment: No Error. It doesn't say any message. I am assuming in that case it saved. I have this tool called SQLiteManager ,a addon by firefox. There i can query the underlying sqlite table. And when i do select * from table name its 0.No values. And i made my web service return me only one record. Still no values.